# net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I get this error on my chrome console

```
GET http://deard.herokuapp.com/static/js/third-party/browser.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 
(index):29 GET http://deard.herokuapp.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

When i comment these two files out in the code, the site loads perfectly (looks weird, of course) 
Also I can see in the developer console that the file does get loaded fine on the frontend with status code 200 OK.

Why would this length mismatch be happening?

This is a flask-socketio app hosted on heroku (using gunicorn). The site works perfectly fine locally.

Comment: What version of gunicorn?

Comment: @miguel : gunicorn 18.0

the server is behaving very inconsistently. A friend adviced me to use whitnoise to serve static files. Which i did and then the site began to work but then this morning i get these errors again.

Comment: I've moved all my static assets to amazon s3 for now and the site works again. lets see if it breaks again...

Comment: It might mean your disk is full, make sure it has free space.